# ASP.NET server control property issue(?)

Tags: asp.net, controls, properties

I am working on some ASP.NET Server Control, and I have an issue.
Maybe I oversee something, I don't know.

Anyway:

```
public string Name
{
    get
    {
        String s = (String)ViewState["name"];
        return ((s == null) ? String.Empty : s);
    }

    set
    {
        ViewState["name"] = value;
    }
}



protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
    txt.ID = Name; // Name here exists
    txt.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

    txt.RenderControl(output);

    output.Write(someName(someValue));

}

public string GetCalendarString(string date)
{
    some code...
    // Name property is null
}
```

'RenderContents' uses property 'Name' to set the control name and then calls 'someName' function and 'someName' function also uses property 'Name', but when I run it, property 'Name' inside function 'someName' is empty, although in 'RenderContents' it is not.

Gremlins, or I'm missing something?

Comment: Do you have a complete example?

Comment: So isolate the bits which are relevant. Chances are that while isolating the relevant bits, you'll find the problem. You certainly haven't given us enough information yet.

Comment: Although, I can exclude the function and post the RenderContents and property.

Comment: This is probably a rendering/page lifecycle problem.  You need to make sure you are looking for the value at a time when it has been set.

Comment: I was going to answer with exactly what Dave said.  Luckily I read the comments first.  Dave, throw him a link to the page lifecycle in a real answer, because you're completely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is going to be tough to answer because without debugging there will be no way to tell what outside forces have manipulated the data.

Since `Name` is a public property any control that has access to it could set it to `null` at any point prior to your call to `GetCalendarString`.  Also if you are calling `GetCalendarString` before `ViewState` is loaded this value will not be available.  I *suspect* that you are trying to get `Name` from `ViewState` before it has loaded but again this is a problem best solved by debugging.

By the way - [here is a great image](http://codebetter.com/blogs//images/codebetter_com/raymond.lewallen/89/o_aspNet_Page_LifeCycle.jpg) that shows the ASP.NET life cycle and will help you figure out if you are trying to use `ViewState` before it is loaded from the `Request`.

Comment: Strange. I've just debugged it and Name field inside a function wasn't null.
Then I rendered the Name property, and it wasn't null either.
Don't know what happened.

Anyway, thank you all for your help and time.